# About Updating Air SDK

Tags: apache-flex, sdk, air

On windows, I downloaded air SDK and copied all files into sdks\4.6.0 ,set namespace air/3.9 , swf-version=22 in my project.Everything went fine.

But on my mac,when I need to test my iOS ANE,I did the same thing as on windows,downloaded SDK and copied files into sdks/4.6.0 but flash builder starts to tell me that there's no flex SDK,so I can't create a new flex mobile project. I tried to copy all files in my downloaded SDK folder into eclipse/plugins/...complier/AIR SDK and came up with repository explorer of flash builder `BROKEN`!

does anyone know how exactly I have to  do to `upgrade my air SDK to the latest version` ,`ON MAC` ? (I'm using flex)

Comment: Worth noting that you will need to update to the latest 4.0 SDK (released late last week) if you want to publish to the App Store.

Comment: Possibly a bit late to the party, but I recently updated the AIR SDK on a Windows FlashBuilder install, and there was a warning on the main AIR SDK download page, "Note: Flex users will need to download the original AIR SDK without the new compiler."  Possibly you downloaded the full SDK and wiped out the original Flex SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent version of Flex is actually Apache Flex. Download the [installer](http://flex.apache.org/installer.html) which is an air app (will work for windows or mac). It will install any version of Air/Flex SDK that you want. I would then put that in the Flash Builder/ SDK's folder and label appropriately. I can't remember the exact path off the top of my head but it should be in the main FB folder. Then in the project poperties set the flex version to the version you installed via the Apache installer.

Answer (score 0):

With Apache Flex on OSX run the addAIRtoSDK.sh script found in the ide directory like so:

```
./addAIRtoSDK.sh 3.9 ..
```

You can run this several time on the same SDK to change the AIR version as required.